# Unable to load model saved using fastai 2.7.11 SaveModelCallback

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, time-series, fast-ai

I am using tsai 0.3.5 and fastai 2.7.11 to save and load the timeseries classifier model.
I am unable to load the saved model when saved using fastai SaveModelCallback.
However when i save using learner.export in tsai library I am able to load.

Below is my code for training and saving the model.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.environ["DEVICE"] = "cuda"
from pickle import load
import numpy as np
from tsai.all import *
from fastai.callback.tracker import SaveModelCallback

dataset_idx = 0
print("training info:", dataset_idx)
X_train = load(open(r"X_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb')).transpose((0,2,1))
y_train = load(open(r"y_train_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
X_test = load(open(r"X_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb')).transpose((0,2,1))
y_test = load(open(r"y_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
l = X_train.shape[0]
X = np.concatenate([X_train, X_test],axis=0)
del X_train, X_test
y = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test],axis=0)
del y_train, y_test
print("dataset loaded")
learn = TSClassifier(X, y, splits = [list(range(l)), list(range(l, y.shape[0]))], arch=InceptionTimePlus, bs=256, arch_config=dict(fc_dropout=0.5), shuffle_train=True)
print("training started")
learn.fit_one_cycle(3, 0.001, cbs=SaveModelCallback(monitor='valid_loss', fname="ITP_"+str(dataset_idx)))
del X, y
```

and below is the code for testing the data:-

```
import pandas as pd
from pickle import load
from tsai.all import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from tsai.inference import load_learner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_test = load(open(r"y_test2_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb'))
X_test = load(open(r"X_test_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pkl", 'rb')).transpose((0,2,1))
learn = load_learner(str("ITP_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pth"))
```

I am getting below error while loading the model saved using fastai:-

```
learn = load_learner(str("ITP_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pth"))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[40], line 1
    learn = load_learner(str("ITP_"+str(dataset_idx)+".pth"))

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\learner.py:451 in load_learner
    res.dls.cpu()

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'dls'
```